# There is no useEffect function anywhere, but I get the Maximum update depth exceeded warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-konva, konva

This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krXwk.png) comes only when the **developer tool** is open in the browser and I do not use a `useEffect` function anywhere in the code that will cause this error.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Layer, Stage } from "react-konva";
import URLImage from "./URLImage";
import Shapes from "../Shapes";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  handleHighlighted,
  mouseDown,
  mouseMove,
  mouseUp,
  setStage,
} from "../../store/general";
import { getMousePos } from "../../helpers";
import useHotkeys from "../../hooks/useHotkeys";
import ContextMenu from "../ContextMenu";
import { useRef } from "react";

const ImageCanvas = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector(
    (state) => state.general,
    (a, b) =>
      a.stageAttrs === b.stageAttrs &&
      a.selectedTool === b.selectedTool &&
      a.selectedImage === b.selectedImage &&
      a.contextMenuOptions.region === b.contextMenuOptions.region
  );
  const stageRef = useRef();

  const handleMouse = (op, e) => {
    e.evt.preventDefault();
    const { x, y } = getMousePos(e);
    switch (op) {
      case "down":
        dispatch(handleHighlighted({ target: e.target.className }));
        dispatch(
          mouseDown({
            x,
            y,
            mouseButton: e.evt.button,
          })
        );
        break;
      case "up":
        dispatch(mouseUp({ x, y }));
        break;
      case "move":
        dispatch(mouseMove({ x, y }));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

 // ...

  return (
    <>
      <Stage
        ref={stageRef}
        draggable={state.stageAttrs.draggable}
        style={{
          cursor: state.selectedTool === "select" ? "unset" : "crosshair",
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
        }}
        width={state.stageAttrs.width}
        height={state.stageAttrs.height}
        x={state.stageAttrs.x}
        y={state.stageAttrs.y}
        scaleX={state.stageAttrs.scale}
        scaleY={state.stageAttrs.scale}
        onWheel={handleWheel}
        onDragStart={(e) => handleDrag(e, "start")}
        onDragEnd={(e) => handleDrag(e, "end")}
        onDblClick={handleDblClick}
        onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
        onMouseDown={(e) => handleMouse("down", e)}
        onMouseUp={(e) => handleMouse("up", e)}
        onMouseMove={(e) => handleMouse("move", e)}
      >
        <Layer>
          <URLImage
            imageData={state.images[state.selectedImage]}
            stageAttrs={state.stageAttrs}
          />
          <Shapes />
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
      {state.contextMenuOptions.region && state.selectedTool === "select" && (
        <ContextMenu />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageCanvas;
```

```
// mouseMove function
    mouseMove: (state, action) => {
      const { x, y } = action.payload;
      if (state.mode) {
        const activeImage = state.images[state.selectedImage];
        const region = state.images[state.selectedImage]?.regions?.find(
          (r) => r.id === state.mode.regionID
        );
        switch (state.mode.mode) {
          case "DRAW_BOX": {
            state.images[state.selectedImage].regions = activeImage.regions.map(
              (r) =>
                r.id === region.id
                  ? { ...r, w: x - region.x, h: y - region.y }
                  : r
            );
            break;
          }
          case "DRAW_POLYGON": {
            state.images[state.selectedImage].regions = activeImage.regions.map(
              (r) =>
                r.id === region.id
                  ? { ...r, points: [...r.points.slice(0, -1), [x, y]] }
                  : r
            );
            break;
          }
```

There is no useEffect function anywhere, but I get the Maximum update depth exceeded warning.

Comment: Can you share the code of `mouseMove` function?

Comment: @mthan please make a very minimal demo.